# Calculate time difference in VBA for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to calculate the time difference between 2 cells and the result showing in the 3rd cell of a MS WORD TABLE.
For instance, cell D2 showing 2pm and D1 showing 1pm and the difference in cell B2

```
Sub DetermineDuration()
    Dim dtDuration As Date

    dtDuration = DateDiff("h:mm:ss", D2, D1)
    Range("B2").dtDuration
End Sub
```

Comment: Ranges and Cells... that is Excel, not Word. Fixed the tags accordingly.

Comment: I was looking for assistance in Word VBA. Specifically calculating time difference in a word table

Answer (score 1):

Dates can be subtracted like numbers:

```
Sub DetermineDuration()
    Range("B2") = Range("D2") - Range("D1")
End Sub
```

Make sure to format cell B2 as `Time` our you will just end up with a floating point number.

Comment: @Nihal Costa: Does this solve your problem? If so, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateDiff` function to return a specific interval type, like hours, minutes or seconds, without precision. It returns a regular number, not a time value. In the *interval* parameter you have to specify a valid interval value. You can learn about the function and see the valid interval values here [MS Excel: How to use the DATEDIFF Function (VBA)](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php)

```
yyyy    Year
q   Quarter
m   Month
y   Day of year
d   Day
w   Weekday
ww  Week
h   Hour
n   Minute
s   Second
```

As you can see, "h:mm:ss" is not a valid interval. You can use this format to get the seconds difference:

```
DateDiff("s", Range("D2"), Range("D1"))
```

If you want to get a time value, you can convert using the `TimeSerial` function.